# Getting Url address from action in Class in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I would like to ask if I am in controller I can enter such command the get the url address

```
var callback = Url.Action(nameof(action), "controller", new { Id = paramter }, Request.Scheme);
```

How could I get the same url if I am in the class instead.

I have tried using urlHelper but I couldn't figure out the action context.

This is the some of the code

```
    public class GeneratePOReminder : IGeneratePOReminder
    {
    private readonly WorkshopProContext db;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public GeneratePOReminder(WorkshopProContext _db, IEmailSender emailSender, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        db = _db;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }


    public void SendReminder()
    {

        var domainaddress = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["Home"].ToString();
        // this is where I get the null error
```

Comment: use like this to get host path and api path HttpContext.Request.Host + HttpContext.Request.Path;

Comment: HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl() or use this direct to get full url

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is suppose to work but I am getting it when the apps started cause I use to schedule task. There I get a null value error.

Comment: Have you tried with HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString()/HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString()

Comment: ok, please add some more code

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I am getting same error

Comment: It shouldn't be RouteValues["Home"] ,Home is the value not key by default...

Comment: key key should be controller